# Не выполняется метод повторно

Tags: java, android

В сервисе, в методе: `onStartCommand` вызываю метод `isOnline();` .

```
int onStatus = 2; //значение по умолчанию
```

В методе `isOnline()` хочу сделать выполнение цикла если onStatus  = 2 , если это так, выполняется код метода, где сразу проверяет соединение с интернетом -> Устанавливаю значение переменной **onStatus = 1**, для того чтоб цикл не начал тут же выполнятся заново. После в этом методе вызываю метод `someTask()` - в котором я осуществляю парсинг сайта, и после получения результата устанавливаю значение переменной **onStatus = 2** , чтобы снова выполнился цикл в методе `isOnline()`. 
Но цикл уже не выполняется... Я подозреваю что это из-за того что в метод новое значение переменной `onStatus` не передается после выполнения метода `someTask()` .

Код метода `someTask()` :

```
 void someTask() {
      new Thread(new Runnable() {

              public void run() {

              Document doc = null;
               try {
                   Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect("http://mobayle.ru/aut.php")
                            .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                            .execute();
                   response = Jsoup.connect("http://mobayle.ru/login.php")
                           .header("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8")
                           .data("nick", loginAuth
                                ,"pass", passAuth)
                           .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                           .timeout(30000).execute();


                    doc = Jsoup.connect("http://mobayle.ru").cookies(response.cookies()).get();
                    Element blockRega = doc.select("div.foot").first();
                    nav2Reg = blockRega.text();

                    Element usInfo = doc.select("div.nav1").first();
                    usName = usInfo.text();

                    Elements kollMess = doc.select("a[href*=new_mess] div.nav2 font[color=red]");
                    kollNewMess = kollMess.text();
                    System.out.println(kollNewMess);
                    } catch (IOException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
               System.out.println(nav2Reg);
               onStatus = 2;  

              }
        }).start();


  }
```

Код метода `isOnline()`:

```
        void isOnline() {

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo nInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        while (onStatus == 2) {
            if (nInfo != null && nInfo.isConnected()) {
            System.out.println("Я ОНЛАЙН");
            onStatus = 1;
            someTask();
            }
            else {
            System.out.println("OFFLINE");
            onStatus = 2;
            }
        }
    }
```

Прошу помощи в решении данной проблемы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Неработоспособность вашего кода связанна с непониманием того в какой последовательности и как выполняется код в разных потоках. В вашем коде вы запускаете цикл `while` который выполняется до того момента, пока переменная `onStatus` равна `2`. В этом цикле вы проверяете доступность интернета, и если он доступен, то вы устанавливаете переменной `onStatus` значение `1` и запускаете метод `someTask`. В этом методе вы **создаете**(именно создаете, а не выполняете код написанный в методе `run`) объект `Thread` и запускаете его. После того как вы запустили поток, метод `someTask` закончил свое выполнение, а с ним и закончил выполняться код в цикле, поэтому происходит проверка условия цикла для того чтобы решить завершить цикл или запустить его еще на 1 круг. А так как перед вызовом метода `someTask` переменной `onStatus` было присвоено значение `1`, то цикл завершается. То что вы в новом потоке в конце выполнения устанавливаете переменной значение `2` никак не повлияет на работу цикла, т.к. он уже давно закончен. Код написанный в методе `run` будет выполняться параллельно с кодом в вашем цикле.

Что бы ваш код заработал вам надо запустить сервис в отдельном потоке, убрать статусы, и их проверку из цикла `while`, в методе `someTask` не создавать новый поток, а просто выполнить код из метода `run`. Т.е. код может выглядеть прмиерно так:

```
void isOnline() {

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo nInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    while (true) {
        if (nInfo != null && nInfo.isConnected()) {
            System.out.println("Я ОНЛАЙН");
            someTask();
        }
    }
}

void someTask() {
    //парсим сайт      
}
```

Однако идея выполнять все это в бесконечном цикле является плохой и лучше использовать, например, [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html), создать задачу и запускать ее с определенным интервалом.